# Computer wakes via mouse but not keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, sleep, wake-up

I have a Windows 10 computer (Asrock x370 Professional Gaming motherboard) and I have enabled in UEFI the ACPI setting which says it would allow wake from USB. I have also checked the Windows power plan settings and the device manager to allow both devices to wake the computer.

However, only the mouse click does so successfully. The keyboard is powered on (LEDs on even if PC powered off), but no keypresses wake the computer.

What other troubleshooting options do I have?

Comment: Try this - https://superuser.com/questions/632077/wireless-mouse-keyboard-wont-wake-sleeping-computer